# Is there a way to change which dict Python instantiates when using {}?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to tell the python interpreter to use a custom inherited dict type in place of dict whenever/wherever a dict would otherwise be instantiated, such as `foo={}`? Or does this require modifying the sources and recompiling?

Comment: The latter. It's deliberate, too, that this impossible; "spooky action at a distance" is contrary to the Zen of Python; we leave that kind of foolishness to people in the Ruby world. ("Explicit is better than implicit", "readability counts", "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules"; when you make syntax mean different things depending on which libraries have been previously imported, that's surprising readers by introducing implicit behavior for what is presumably a special-case purpose).

Comment: It _might_ be possible by modifying `globals()['__builtins__']`.  But even then, it might only catch `dict()`, not `{}`.

Comment: point taken, still leaves me wondering (with less hope), whether it would (have) be possible for my own code at least, even for other operators.

Comment: and maybe you want the `[]` creates a new `MyClass` object

Comment: I experimented with [forbiddenfruit](https://clarete.li/forbiddenfruit/), but was unable to find a way to curse `dict.__new__()` into returning a subclass of dict. Might be something that's hardcoded in the Python interpreter for speed - dicts are used all over the place, after all.

Comment: Somewhat  related: there's an [open PEP for syntactic macros](https://peps.python.org/pep-0638/) that would let you create user-defined literals of a sort

Comment: How about using a decorator?

Comment: There's actually a weirder way to do this: [custom codecs](https://github.com/ssize-t/inlinec) or import hooks let you rewrite modules during parsing so you could swap out dict literals for custom type instantiation (although you would need to beware of set literals). I couldn't recommend agains this enough tough, just instantiate your custom collection like a normal person.

Comment: The executor will use the dict C API (I think its `_PyDict_FromItems`) so it wouldn't help to muck around with the methods on `dict`. It seems that rewriting the byte code executor is the way to go. Although you could rewrite the dict C API instead.

Comment: I found something that almost works. I found a library called codetransformer, which is a library for rewriting function bytecode. It has a decorator called [overloaded_dicts()](https://github.com/llllllllll/codetransformer/blob/master/codetransformer/transformers/literals.py#L16), which can be used as a decorator to replace dictionary literals with a custom type, such as OrderedDict. However, it seems to not have been updated past Python 3.6.